# Not able to scrape the person ID data using Beautiful Soup in tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm not able to scrape the user ID in table in `<span` tag. This is my code

```
my_url='https://combot.org/telegram/top/chats/?lng=en&page='+str(page) 
request = urllib.request.Request(my_url,None,hdr)
uClient=ureq(request) 
page_html=uClient.read()       
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")   
first=page_soup.find("table")
print(first.findAll("span",{"class":"card-username"}))
```

I'm just getting an empty list
[image]

Comment: paste the entire part of URL the "page" you  concat with my_url

Comment: Spelling; grammar; layout.